# What command do I put into a command block that can set the spawn of the nearest player to a different specific location?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to use the command block to set the nearest player's spawn to a specific location, how to I do it? And will the player spawn there if he dies?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `/setspawn @p 50 64 50`.  `@p` targets the nearest player, and `50 64 50` is the x,y and z coordinates. If the set player dies they will respawn at the set coordinates.

Comment: The question specifically asks for the /setspawn variation for the closest user, since /tp teleports the player, it doesn't set spawn. If that option exists, that is.

Comment: @Arperum that option exists. The appropriate command would be `/spawnpoint @p x y z`

Answer (score 0):

/setspawn @p in the command block to set the spawn. But you need to be in opped creative to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is set a team spawn, this can be done by using this:

[c1]=*****=[c2]

(c1 = /scoreboard teams join (Team) @p )

(c2 = /setspawn @a[team=(Team)] x y z)

(=) = Repetor

(*) = Redstone

Answer (score 0):

Use /tp @p [x] [y] [z] This will teleport the nearest player to a specific location.